# How to move all files with fewer than 5 bytes in BASH?

Tags: bash, filesize, mv

I have a folder containing many audio files, but some are ~4 bytes and seem to contain nothing, they are 0 seconds long and have no sound. I want to move them to a folder called "temp/".

How can I move all of the files in the folder that have fewer than 5 bytes to this folder?

Answer (score 25):

## Find!

You can use [find](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) to do this for you:

```
find . -type f -maxdepth 1 -size -5c -exec mv {} temp/ \;
```

## Explanation

`-size -5c` grabs all the files less than 5 bytes. The `-` indicates less than and the `c` indicates bytes.

`-maxdepth 1` prevents you from trying to move the files on top of themselves when it tries to recurse into temp/ (after moving your initial files).

`-exec mv {} temp/ \;` simply runs `mv` on each file to put them in temp (the {} is substituted for the name of the file). The escaped semicolon marks the end of the mv command for exec.

There are other sizes available as well:

```
`b'    for  512-byte blocks (this is the default if no suffix is
       used)
`c'    for bytes
`w'    for two-byte words
`k'    for Kilobytes (units of 1024 bytes)
`M'    for Megabytes (units of 1048576 bytes)
`G'    for Gigabytes (units of 1073741824 bytes)
```

Comment: `-maxdepth 1` is probably quite important, otherwise it would find the ones you've already moved!

Comment: @MatthewSchinckel Heh. That's what took me so long to answer originally. I was testing to make sure my find knowledge was working appropriately, kept getting `'x' and 'x' are the same file`, then I realized it was recursing.

Answer (score 2):

`find -size 1c` will give you all files that are *exactly* one byte.

As [@user1666959](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1666959/user1666959) mentions, you can also use `find . -type f -size -4c`, which will find all files in the current directory (and subdirectories), that are 4 bytes and smaller.

```
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -size -4c -exec mv {} temp/ \;
```

(Yes, you will need the trailing `\;`.

Note that `find -size` allows for other exact file size matches (such as `1k`), but also allows you to search for files that take up the designated number of blocks on the disk (leaving off the unit).

```
$ man find
```

Provides a heap more info about how to use it to search.

Comment: What's wrong with doing it in one go? `find . -type f -size -5c`. The minus sign before the length argument says you want files of size less than 5.

Comment: Nice, that's much cleaner. The man page didn't mention you could do that!

Comment: Would this search skip directories?

Comment: @Basilevs: Do you mean for if there are spaces in the matched filenames? (Oh, and the `-type f` should fix the other bit you mentioned).

Comment: Spaces are of no importance. What bothers me is that. {} are special substitution symbols in bash

Comment: Weird. All the docs for find typically let the {} just hang out there. Does it really have to be escaped @Basilevs?

Comment: I've never escaped {} in my find -exec stuff.

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -size -5c -exec mv '{}' temp/ \;
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be:

`find . -type f -maxdepth 1 | xargs du | sort -n |grep "^[0-5]\t"|sed "s/[0-5]//"|sed "s/^.//"|xargs -I ARG mv ARG temp/`

It finds all files, lists their sizes, sorts by that, takes all that are size 0,1,2,3,4,5, gets just the filenames, and then runs the mv command on them!

Comment: Find has it's own switch for looking at file sizes.